# Why can’t I access object properties in a for-in loop over an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, loops, javascript-objects

I am currently utilizing the SheetSU API to read data from a Google Sheets file.

```
var members = Sheetsu.read("URL", {}, successFunc);
```

For now, the `successFunc` is a function that takes the input `data` to `console.log()` to me.

The data imports like this: `(14){{..},{..},{..}....}` and each object within this dictionary looks something like this:

```
0: {Name: "First Last", ID: "12536723", Status: "Member"}
1: {Name: "First Last", ID: "12371238", Status: "Member"}
...
14: {Name: "First Last", ID: "12341228", Status: "Member"}
```

I need to pull out the values of `Name` and `ID`, however:

```
for (var x in data) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

= `0, 1, 2, ..., 14` (as ints not objects)

```
for (var x in data) {
    console.log(x.Name)
}
```

= `undefined, undefined, ..., undefined`

Comment: See the warning and alternatives about using `for...in` with arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: @Igor Op did not ask about the difference, did not even mention `for of`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684672/1260204)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is not a value It is a `index` like 0,1 ...14, you can use `of` for that or use `data[x]` inside `in`.

```js
var data = [{
        Name: "First Last",
        ID: "12536723",
        Status: "Member"
    }, {
        Name: "First Last",
        ID: "12371238",
        Status: "Member"
    },
    {
        Name: "First Last",
        ID: "12341228",
        Status: "Member"
    }
]

for (var x in data) {

    console.log(data[x].Name); //x is not a value It is a index like 0,1 ...14

}

for (var x of data) {

    console.log(x.Name); // use of which prints x as object not index

}
```

Comment: What's matter down voter It is better to give feedback rather than down voting without any sense!.

Comment: it is the correct answer for me

Comment: Thanks @Emeeus !.