# Javascript range for with array of objects

Tags: javascript

The following piece of code

```
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i in test) {
  console.log(i.region);
}
```

just displays twice `undefined`. What's the problem with an array of objects?

Comment: Try logging just `i`. You should see the mistake immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can’t I access object properties in a for-in loop over an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52190727/4642212)

Comment: The JavaScript for/in statement loops through the properties of an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `for...in` allows you to access the keys of the object but doesn't provide 
>    the reference to the values.

Thus you get the indexes (0 and 1). You can use those indexes to access the object property.

```js
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i in test) {
  console.log(test[i].region);
}
```

Please Note: [Array iteration and for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

> > `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

You mean to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

```js
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i of test) {
  console.log(i.region);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `for(var i in test)` then `i` will be an iterator, meaning its value will be `0,1,2,...n` where n is the index of the last element in the array.

So to solve your issue, you will have to use `i` in conjunction with `test` array as such

```
test[i].region
```

not just

```
i.region
```

```js
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i in test) {
  console.log(test[i].region);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is used to iterate over properties of an object. Here, for e.g. the properties will be 0, 1, etc.

To iterate over arrays, use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i of test) {
  console.log(i.region);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For arrays you can use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Code:

```js
const test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

test.forEach(i => console.log(i.region));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [
  {region: 'ap', tl: 'lol'},
  {region: 'ew', tl: 'asd'}
];

for(var i in test) {
  console.log(test[i].region);
}
```