# Iterate over the inline defined array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How to iterate over the inline defined array by used of this structure of for loop and access values of the array?

```
for(let prop in ["Alan", "Jeff", "Sarah", "Ryan"]){
   //"Alan"
   //"Jeff"
   //"Sarah"
   //"Ryan"
}
```

Comment: `in` should be `of` ;)

Comment: [Why can’t I access object properties in a for-in loop over an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52190727/4642212) is a better dupe target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `of` instead of `in`

```
for(let prop of ["Alan", "Jeff", "Sarah", "Ryan"]){
    console.log(prop);
}
```

will output:

```
Alan
Jeff
Sarah
Ryan
```